How to confirm whether a server is configured as a Remote Desktop Services session host?
My team is using an Azure Virtual Machine.
We are limited to two concurrent connections as described here:

A maximum of two concurrent connections are supported, unless the
server is configured as a Remote Desktop Services session host.*

I would like to understand how the server could be configured as a Remote Desktop Services session host.
Is this something done under the Azure Portal when provisioning the VM, or is it enabled on the VM after it has been created?

This two-connection limit is for administrative purposes only, intended for managing the server and applies to Windows Servers in general. To allow more than two users to connect simultaneously, the server must be configured as a  RDS session host - also known as Terminal Server, which requires purchasing RDS Client Licenses. This needs to be done after VM provisioning, by installing the Remote Desktop Services role and configuring licensing.

Thanks for your answer @hakim00.
